# How can I find the treasure from the treasure map?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In my Game I found two treasure maps. but I can't understand what they show to me and where the treasure is supposed to be?

So in this case the treasure map is split into two parts (top and bottom). Can anyone describe what these parts mean?

Comment: There are different treasure maps as far as I know, it might help if you add a screenshot of the map.

Comment: I've found 2,3 and 4. I thought they were all hints to the one treasure... I have no idea

Comment: @Xenox - Spoiler tags should only be used for questions with spoilers in the title, not questions asking for spoiler answers, as per the tag wiki.

Comment: I think there is no global rule about treasure map's. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the treasure maps show the location of a separate treasure. If you can't figure out the location there are several video guides on youtube showing you how to get to the treasure.

One of the most complete is a [guide to all 10 treasure maps by DestinStrider](http://www.youtube.com/user/DestinStrider#p/u/9/eUqu9ZfY35c).

Answer (score 1):

If it is the treasure map with the trees on the right with houses on the top half, and a bridge with water on the bottom half then this is the Haafingar Hold—Dragon Bridge map. The top half treasure is in a satchel behind a tree across the bridge which gives you a key. The second treasure is underwater northeast of the bridge.

If it is the treasure map with the lighthouse it's just up on the hill behind the lighthouse.